# React instantiate data before render

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON file consisting of a bunch of data that I need to feed into a child componet upon rendering the page. I tried using `componentDidMount` however, from the docs (and console log results) the page is actually rendering the first time before the data is fetched, then re-rendered with the fetched data, fast enough that the screen doesn't refresh. The problem is the first render.

```
state = {
     moduleJSON: ""
}
request = async () => {
      let response = await fetch("./AllModules.json");
      let json = await response.json();
      console.log("moduleJSON");
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({moduleJSON: json})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.request();
  }
```

I am feeding this.state.moduleJSON into a child component, which it then uses the data to build the components I need. However since the very first render doesn't fetch the data from the JSON, my first render crashes because in the child component I am reading a variable of undefined.

Is there a way to read data from a JSON and store it as a variable before or concurrently with the very first render?

Comment: Post the child component here... You're basically talking about handling null props which could be done with an && before the render...

Comment: Thanks! Adding the conditional handling actually solved the problem, at first I thought that adding this handler would cause the render to first appear blank, refresh, and then re-render the appropriate components